# WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb"

Tags: php, pecl

What does that pecl message mean? 
I mean specifically how does one use the channel described in the error message?
... or in other words how can I address this error (but not specific to mongo, i.e. I get this failure not just when trying to install Mongo but also when trying to install other things and I don't understand how to fix it in general).

Should I be "installing" the channel via pecl somehow? (Much like one adds a channel to yum).

Or what?

Comment: dont know the answer sorry but I am interested to understand what this means too.

Comment: Got the same warning on ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5 and apache2. How did you solved it ?

Comment: I haven't solved it. Why don't you guys vote the question up? Maybe more people will notice it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It simply means that `mongo` extension is deprecated, and you should use `mongodb` instead:

```
pecl install mongodb
```

Comment: And the version numbers have changed. Currently, the latest stable on `mongodb` is 1.1.6. On the deprecated `mongo` it was 1.6.14.